# Object isn't a valid JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

My JsonString:

```
{"Data":{"pics":{"24":{"ID":"24","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/010.jpg"},"23":{"ID":"23","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/009.jpg"},"22":{"ID":"22","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/008.jpg"},"21":{"ID":"21","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/007.jpg"},"20":{"ID":"20","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/006.jpg"},"19":{"ID":"19","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/005.jpg"},"18":{"ID":"18","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/004.jpg"},"17":{"ID":"17","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/003.jpg"},"16":{"ID":"16","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/002.jpg"},"15":{"ID":"15","LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/001.jpg"},"14":{"ID":"14","LINK":"http:\/\/orf.at\/mojo\/1_1\/storyserver\/\/news\/images\/logo.newsorfon.png"}}},"Message":null,"Code":200}
```

I want to parse it to get the id and the link into my treemap.

My Code:

```
JSONObject parse = new JSONObject(msg.obj.toString());
                JSONObject data = parse.getJSONObject("Data");
                JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray("pics");
                for (int i = 0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    list.put(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("ID")), obj.getString("LINK"));
                    Log.e("FunPics",obj.getString("ID")+ " " + obj.getString("LINK"));
                }
```

Error:

> 11-21 11:32:21.005: W/System.err(393): org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["pics"] is not a JSONArray.
>   11-21 11:32:21.015: W/System.err(393): at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:366)

Comment: put the json string in json array i mean put "msg.obj.toString()" into getJSONArray() instead of "pics" and then using for loop get "pics" as a jsonobject...!! and One "more" thing is the JSONString coming from webservice is wrong it must come in [{Data:......}] format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pics` is not an array, it's an object, array is indicated by being in `[` and `]` (as specified [here](http://www.json.org/)):

```
{
"Data":{
    "pics":{
        "24":{
            "ID":"24",
            "LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/010.jpg"
        },
        "23":{
            "ID":"23",
            "LINK":"http:\/\/www.orschlurch.net\/wp-content\/gallery\/pixxdump-144\/009.jpg"
        },
    }
},
....
"Message":null,
"Code":200
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"pics" is a jsonObject not a jsonArray so write `data.getJSONObject("pics")` in place of `data.getJSONArray("pics");`

Answer (score 1):

pics key has jsonObject as value not a jsonArray.

`JSONObject picsJson = data.getJSONObject("pics");`

you have to iterate through all the keys and get each information of picture. use keys iterator, check the link below,

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
Iterator keys = picsJson.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
```